# Anime movie from the late 90's/early 2000 where a scientist tortures people until they develop powers

Tags: story-identification, anime

I caught the last 30min of the film and at the time I didn't have one of those TVs that shows the name of the program being played at that moment, and I haven't been able to find it since.

Here's what I recall:

- A woman in a high-tech (evangelion-like) suit with super strength, fighting with some soldiers/mechas if I recall correctly, and breaking into a military base-like facility.
- Two young adults, a guy and a girl, that were inside the said facility. They are being tortured (getting shocked or something like that), and later the guy develop a material absorption power (like turning into metal by copying the properties of a metal panel). The girl develops a power too but I can't remember what it is.
- An evil scientist that tortures people until their mutation manifest. He has a telekinetic ability that he uses to attack and levitate.

The film is brutal and has a Street Fighter II kind of style but with more contrasted colors. A mix of anime style with comics colors/shading.

Thank you for the help.